# Is Java-like restrictiveness OK Python style?

Tags: java, python, coding-style

Good Pythonic style  is much looser than Java's uptight restrictiveness:

In Java, good style means `private` on methods wherever possible,  all fields encapsulated, type declarations, defined interfaces  including `abstract` methods.

All this is now doable in Python, but good style allows and encourages public members, duck-typing, etc.

Yet I find all that to be quite useful. IDE's, for example, can do much more with these declarations in place. SO, I often do these things in Python, much more than examples of good Pythonic code that I find.

Is it actually *bad style* to do these things?

Comment: I'm no expert, but readers of Python code expect it to be written a certain way. For example, in Java, if you need to expose the private member of a class, you would use a getter, in Python, while you can write a getter, it's better practice to just expose the variable naturally. Following Java style conventions in Python might not be a good idea.

Comment: "All this is now doable in Python": What do you mean? As far as I know, everything is public in Python, there are only naming conventions to mark members that are private, but the language does not prevent the programmer from accessing them directly from outside the class in which they are defined.

Comment: I used to code in LISP some 20 years ago, and the main problem with big real-world applications was the lack of strict typing (it was possible with declarations, but not typical LISP style). We got the weirdest runtime errors. I appreciate the strictness of Java, allowing to see and repair many problems already in the IDE, at compile time.

Comment: I like a strict type system for two reasons. Code completion and compile time errors. Of the two compile time errors that tell me when I've used a string where an int is expected is my favorite. They're like terse little unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat surprisingly, Python gives you a lot of choice here. Most Python code is fairly informal regarding exact types, and whether some attribute is part of the public interface. This works fine, until it doesn't. In particular, maintaining large projects is more challenging in dynamic languages like Python.

But as the Zen of Python says: Explicit is better than implicit.

Python has been moving towards *enabling* but not requiring a stricter style. Importantly, recent Python versions add syntax for type annotations. While these annotations are comparatively limited and have no runtime effect (they are usually processed by external type checkers such as mypy) they make it more feasible to use static typing in parts of your code. Whether this is feasible depends on what modules are using, since most modules do not provide any type annotations of their own, and some do not even have interfaces that can be typed.

This is a bit similar to JavaScript vs. TypeScript: type checking (with all its benefits like better semantic autocompletion in editors) is available if you want it, but you're in no way forced to declare your types.

So if you feel like this helps you keep your code maintainable …

- make use of docstrings
- use type annotations
- use external checkers and linters such as mypy and pylint
- prefer read-only properties over directly assigning public attributes
- create explicit interfaces (e.g. using the `abc.ABC` base class)
- explicitly `assert` your function preconditions, e.g.:

  ```
  assert isinstance(param, SomeInterface), \
      f"param must be SomeInterface, but was {type(param)}"`
  ```

The Python code I write tends to do this, in moderation. Especially because the static type checking is a later add-on, it is quite limited and doesn't always work. And it's really not worth meticulously encapsulating every attribute as you'd do in Java. But stronger checks help catching bugs early, so being a bit more explicit than usual can be a good idea.